# How to sequence my data table using linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that looks like below:

| ItemName | ItemPro

```
 A         HWH  
 A         BRB  
 A         EAH  
 B         HWH  
 B         BRB  
 B         EAH  
 B         HWH  
 C         BRB  
 C         EAH
```

I want to group above `DataTable` by `ItemName` and sort these groups

How can I achieve this?

Note: after sorting, I want my table like below;

| ItemName | ItemPro

```
 A         HWH  
 B         BRB  
 c         EAH  
 A         HWH  
 B         BRB  
 C         EAH  
 A         HWH  
 B         BRB  
 B         EAH
```

Comment: You have sorted datatable and want to un-sort it?

Comment: woww,. that Ghost edit just made the question completely opposite to what it was before.

Comment: @Habib I believe that is by mistake (otherwise it does not make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to group your values by `ItemName` instead you can apply sorting on `ItemName` like:

```
var sortedQuery = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(r=> r.Field<string>("ItemName"));
```

If you want the second field to be sorted as well then use `Enumerable.ThenBy` like:

```
var sortedQuery = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
        .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemPro"));
```

If you want result in a new `DataTable` then:

```
DataTable sortedDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
                        .ThenBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemPro"))
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: kindly see my question which I updated and revert me back. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @user3752669, you don't need group by , you can use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` for second field.

Answer (score 0):

var listOfStrings = new List{
    "Orange",
    "Orange",
    "Orange",
    "Orange",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Mango",
    "Apple",
    "Apple",
    "Apple"
};

```
        var groupedStrings = listOfStrings.GroupBy(i => i)
            .Select(i => new { i.Key, Items = i.ToList() }).ToList();

        var maxGroupSize = groupedStrings.OrderByDescending(i => i.Items.Count).First()
            .Items.Count;

        var finalList = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < maxGroupSize; i++)
        {
            finalList.AddRange(from wordGroup in groupedStrings
                               where i < wordGroup.Items.Count
                               select wordGroup.Items[i]);
        }
```